# Uno to Mega and where is the error for the interrupt that isn't delared?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, interrupt, rotary-encoder

I want to read a Omron E6B2-CWZ6C Incremental Rotary Encoder w/Index (360P/R).
A couple questions, I found out that an Uno can only handle 2 interrupt pins and I think I need 3 for the Index.  What do I need to do to the following code to get it to run on a Mega which I believe can handle 3 interrupt pins?

Also I am getting a 'outAChange' was not declared in this scope.
What am I missing here.

I will be using the data from the encoder value to run a NeoPixel 60 for a directional mast/antenna.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
// Wiring connections for my encoder:
// Brown : VCC = 5 to 24VDC
// Blue: 0V(Common) = GND
// Shield: GND
// Black: outA = Digital pin 2
// White: outB = Digital pin 3
// Orange: outZ = Digital pin 4 (Index)
// With these outA/outB/outZ connections and the interrupt code below
// clockwise rotation gives positive encoder counts

const int outA = 2;
const int outB = 3;
const int outZ = 4;

volatile long encoder = 0; // declare volatile since modified by interrupt routines
float encoder_save = 0;

void setup(){  // set encoder pins
pinMode(outA, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(outB, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(outZ, INPUT_PULLUP);  //Index

// attach interrupts to pins
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outA), outAChange, CHANGE);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outB), outBChange, CHANGE);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outZ), outZChange, CHANGE);

// initialize serial
Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop(){ 

if (encoder_save != encoder)  // only print if new value
encoder_save = encoder;

// If Index(Z) reads low reset encoder to 0
if (digitalRead(outZ) == LOW)
{
  encoder = 0;
}
}

{
Serial.println((encoder * 360)/360);
}
}

// interrupt routines
void outAChange(){
// when outA changes, outA==outB means negative direction
encoder += digitalRead(outA) == digitalRead(outB) ? -1 : 1;
if (encoder < 0)
{
  encoder = (encoder + 360); 
}
}

void outBChange(){
// when outB changes, outA==outB means positive direction
encoder += digitalRead(outA) == digitalRead(outB) ? 1 : -1;
if (encoder >= 360)
{
  encoder = (encoder - 360);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are all messed up.  If you pass your code through an autoformatter (such as the one included in the IDE) you end up with this:

```
// Wiring connections for my encoder:
// Brown : VCC = 5 to 24VDC
// Blue: 0V(Common) = GND
// Shield: GND
// Black: outA = Digital pin 2
// White: outB = Digital pin 3
// Orange: outZ = Digital pin 4 (Index)
// With these outA/outB/outZ connections and the interrupt code below
// clockwise rotation gives positive encoder counts

const int outA = 2;
const int outB = 3;
const int outZ = 4;

volatile long encoder = 0; // declare volatile since modified by interrupt routines
float encoder_save = 0;

void setup() { // set encoder pins
    pinMode(outA, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(outB, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(outZ, INPUT_PULLUP);  //Index
// attach interrupts to pins
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outA), outAChange, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outB), outBChange, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(outZ), outZChange, CHANGE);
// initialize serial
    Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
    if (encoder_save != encoder) { // only print if new value
        encoder_save = encoder;
    }

// If Index(Z) reads low reset encoder to 0
    if (digitalRead(outZ) == LOW) {
        encoder = 0;
    }
}

{                                                << WHAT
    Serial.println((encoder * 360) / 360);       << IS
}                                                << THIS
}                                                << CODE?

// interrupt routines
void outAChange() {
// when outA changes, outA==outB means negative direction
    encoder += digitalRead(outA) == digitalRead(outB) ? -1 : 1;

    if (encoder < 0) {
        encoder = (encoder + 360);
    }
}

void outBChange() {
// when outB changes, outA==outB means positive direction
    encoder += digitalRead(outA) == digitalRead(outB) ? 1 : -1;

    if (encoder >= 360) {
        encoder = (encoder - 360);
    }
}
```

As you can see, after the end of your `loop()` function, you have an extraneous block of code with a bunch of random brackets.

You need to decide where in your program that should actually be and move it there, deleting those extra brackets.

Comment: I could use a little more help than that.  I am really new at coding.  thanks.

Comment: I cannot help you. Only you know where you want that bit of code.